# How can i make sure that only a single instance of the process on Linux?

Tags: linux

For example:

I code a client process named myProcess .

I will run it 3 times  :  ./myProcess

Then i ps x | grep myProcess, i get this :

```
21662 ?        Ss     0:00 ./myProcess
21758 ?        Ss     0:00 ./myProcess
21878 ?        Ss     0:00 ./myProcess .
```

But what i want is no matter how many times i run it,there's only one instance of
this myProcess.

Somebody suggests me i can do it with the file lock.But is there any other solution ?

Do you guys get some solutions?  thanks.

Comment: The file lock is the normal way - is there some reason you didn't want to do that?

Comment: Or a socket. This question has been answered a million times.